# In GLFW which button defines the X1 and X2 buttons?

Tags: c++, glfw, mouse-buttons

In GLFW. which constant defines the X buttons on the mouse.
The ones on the side of generally gaming mice.

I know that SFML has `sf::Mouse::XButton1` and `sf::Mouse::XButton2` but which one out of the *nine* denotes those buttons in GLFW.

Answer (score 0):

Check the [docs](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/group__buttons.html#ga53f4097bb01d5521c7d9513418c91ca9).

Apparently, GLFW has 12 different mappings for mouse buttons.

Comment: I tried checking the docs and even the comments in the header but to no luck. It only list what's there, not what's what.

Comment: I'd advise you to test the button event against all of these mappings to be sure.

Comment: Sadly I can't I'm using a Logitech mouse, but I re-bound the keys ages ago and they don't have support for linux. So... ;~;